# ChartJS makes unwanted horizontal line on Safari

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, chart.js

I'm currently working with ChartJS.
It works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

On Safari there is horizontal lines which appear. (here there is one good on orange and two others unwanted )
[image]

I have a lot of datapoint (2 lines of 1600 data point). I don't know if it could be a cause.

My code is here.
In some other part, I update time uni and time min.

```
      _displayChart: function(label1, label2){
    var timeFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

    var ctx = document.getElementById(this.heading).getContext('2d');

    const data = {
        // Labels should be Date objects
        //labels:this._stats[1],
        datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            label: label1,
            data: this._stats[2],
            borderColor: '#fe8b36',
            pointRadius: 0,
            backgroundColor: [
            '#fe8b36'
            ]
        },{
            label: label2,
            fill: false,
            data: this._stats[3],
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: 'rgba(99, 100, 200, 1)',
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(99, 100, 200, 0.2)'
            ]
          }]
    }
    const options = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            fill: false,
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio:!this._isMobile(),
            max: this.max,
            hover: {
                // Overrides the global setting
                mode: 'index'
            },
            annotation: {
              drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
              events: ['click'],
              annotations: []
            },
            legend: {
              labels: {
                filter: function(legendItem, chartData) {
                  if(legendItem.datasetIndex == 2 || legendItem.datasetIndex == 3 ){
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                }
              }
            },
            tooltips: {
              mode:'index',
              intersect : false,
              callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                  return tooltipItems[0].xLabel.format(timeFormat);
                }, 
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                  return tooltipItems.yLabel+'%';
                }
              }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    display: true,
                    time:{
                      unit:'day',
                      min:moment(Date.now()-this.monthTs),
                      max:this._stats[1][this._stats[1].length]
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                    display: true
                }]
            }
        }
    }
    this._chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
  },
```

When I'm applying this, I have no problem:

```
          this._chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'month';
      this._chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.stepSize = 1;
      this._chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = this._stats[1][0];
      this._chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = this._stats[1][this._stats[1].length-1];
```

Thanks

Comment: Without code, we can't help you.

Comment: Edited @Niklas Higi